# How do i insert data a field A - to -B in mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables a `user` table and `product`
the `user` is for registering users and login and the `product` is for allowing the user to post his product. just for listing.

The user table would be like this

```
user_id (int)
user name (varchar)
user_email (varchar)
user_password)
```

now i can insert data into and from this table with easily.

In the second table (product table)

```
product_id (int)
product_name (varchar)
product_description(varchar)
```

etc.

i have extra field that says user_id
what i basiclly i want to do is, i want insert the user_id from table 1 into a field in table table. 
so lets say
i have a form for entering product details
the form include
product_id, name, desc etc all as a textfields

when the user fill all field in that forms, considering that the user is already login, so i want know who inserted that data.

i hope that make sense

The code i used for inserting data into  product table is

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

     //Getting values
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $price = $_POST['price'];
     $description= $_POST['description'];

     $userphone = $_POST['userphone'];


     //Creating an sql query
     $sql = "INSERT INTO list (name,price,description userphone) VALUES ('$name','$price','$description','$userphone')";

     //Importing our db connection script
     require_once('dbConnect.php');

     //Executing query to database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
         echo 'Employee Added Successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Add Employee';
     }

    //Closing the database 
    mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

So to emphasis
i want the user_id from table 1 to be inserted into table 2.

thanks

Comment: whne the user logs in put their id in a session, and just use that varable

Comment: agree with nogad, there will have to be some kind or $SESSION/$COOKIE to store their user_id .. since they "register" and "log in" .. you may already have the neccesary values,, try `print_r($SESSION);` to see if you have user names or ids already in their session info

Comment: Also note that code pattern in the question is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Potentially unsafe values included in the text of a SQL statement must be properly escaped. The preferred pattern is to *not* include values in the SQL text, but to supply values using bind placeholders.

Comment: Emphsise all you want. If you did not keep the `user_id` of the logged in user somewhere I cannot emphasis enough, you cannot magic it up from nowhere

Comment: i persume i have used the same code for my android app, and my android uses shared preferences for user session.

Comment: will be ok in my php to have something like this $user_id = $Session['user'], then i say my insert statment, insert into table (user_id) values ('$user_id) or values ('$session['user_id'] after start my session on my php code

Comment: probably ......